# Can I get trusted CA certificate for a local virtual host e.g. https://myapp

Tags: apache, ssl, https

we have an web application(WAMP stack) on a local Windows server. There are several dependencies and an Oracle db running on this server and the server is closed to outside internet traffic.
Clients access the app on LAN using the server's IP, but we plan to create a virtual hostname in active directory to enable access using a hostname on entire local network.

We would like to secure the traffic and switch to https, thus we need a SSL certificate, preferably from a trusted CA to avoid any confusing warnings to the users.

Is there a way to get a Trusted CA SSL certificate for a local host? I was thinking of getting a certificate for a public domain, say myapp.net, then map this domain to actual ip of the local server running the app and install the certificate in apache... would that work?

Thank you for any ideas.
Alexander

Comment: Use FQDN from the get go and not short names, this will save you ton of troubles later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

The public CAs that your browser trusts by default *will only* sign keys for DNS names. And you can totally have a DNS name that is not accessible from the public internet (e.g. one that resolves to a local IP). In case you're using CAs like LetsEncrypt (Domain Validated), you will need to make the server available publicly during the key exchange/certification time, but can change the IP immediately afterwards (*). Or simply use one of the other available validation techniques - typically they're paid.

As you're on the intranet, you might be in a situation where you can install your own internal trusted CA on your users' computers. In that case, you can mint such a certificate yourself. This is a scenario that's common in case there's a proxy running internally that's also inspecting https traffic.

And, of course, in case you can install trusted root CAs on computers, you can also install individual trusted keys/certificates for a single machine. But that seems not to be what you'd like to do.

So, for `https://myapp` you'll have to do some minting/installation yourself. For `https://myapp.example.com`, you have options with (already) trusted root CAs

(*) that is for the commonly used and documented mode-of-operation. See Patrick's comment below

Comment: " you will need to make the server available publicly during the key exchange/certification time," That is not even necessary if you do the dns-01 challenge instead of http-01.

Comment: Thank you - I rarely touch new systems, so this is not top of my mind. I've edited it in.

Comment: Thank you both for answers, we will try the DNS-01 challenge and if that fails for a reason, we will stick to self issued certificate and install it on every client pc.